# Presenting data and missing data with different style of lines (Matplotlib, plot)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization

I have different series of data, some missing (`NaN`).

I would like to plot a graph, with a solid line connecting data, and a dotted line connected missing data.

I would like to have it on the same plot.

Example

```
0     0.146397
1          NaN
2     0.356559
3          NaN
4          NaN
5          NaN
6          NaN
7     0.146451
8          NaN
9          NaN
10         NaN
11         NaN
Name: mySeries, dtype: object
```

I know I can do:

```
# solid
plt.plot( my_series,  linestyle='-', marker='o')

# dotted, excluding Nan
plt.plot( my_series.dropna(), linestyle=':', marker='o')
```

I thought to superimpose the plots, like:

```
plt.plot( my_series,  linestyle='-', marker='o')
plt.plot( my_series.dropna(), linestyle=':', marker='o')
plt.show
```

but I see that only the last graph is seen  (I am using jupyter, not sure if it a matter of opacity or jupyter, that show only last computed plot).

How could I inform the user which lines reflect real data, and which lines connect missing data, using a same plot ?

(Using pandas, matplotlib, jupyter).

Comment: Without having a reproducible code and your data, no one can guess what's going on in your Jupyter notebook. You should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: edited @Sheldore. is the description of the question clear enough for an answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try each command in a different cell, you will see that the first line looks like scatter. This is because your data indeed scatter around. So I modified it a little:

```
0     0.146
1     0.220
2       NaN
3     0.356
4       NaN
5       NaN
6       NaN
7       NaN
8     0.146
9       NaN
10      NaN
dtype: float64
```

and switched the order of plot, as we want the original plot on top:

```
plt.plot( my_series.dropna(), ':o')
plt.plot(my_series, marker='o')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]